# VBA EXCEL update cell in another workbook without opening the workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I have a directory with list of Workbooks, I want to loop through them *withouth* opening them and update a Cell in a certain Sheet

I have tried to use

```
Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = Workbooks("Z:\dir\bla.xls") 'THIS WILL COME TRHOUGH WHEN I LOOP 
Set ws2 = wb.Sheets("TestSheet") 'SHEET NAME

Set CurCell_2 = ws2.Range("A1")
CurCell_2.Value = 5
```

The Problem comes it only works when I have the Workbook already open. I can use:

```
Workbooks.Open
```

But then It opens up in the background and takes to long to run through them all.

Can anyone help please

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do that without opening the workbooks. However, I have found in my case that using `Application.EnableEvents` and setting it to false sped up greatly the process because we have macros on workbook open event.

Comment: Thanks already using `Application.EnableEvents` thought I could do it without opening the Workbook :(

Comment: Sadly no. The only other option is to manipulate the XML file inside your workbook directly but that's living dangerously.