# Copy the last entry row of a dynamic range and paste into to another workbook without displaying it

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to copy and paste the last entry row of a dynamic range into another workbook without displaying it and without opening it, if it is possible.

For instance in the following case I would like to copy and paste row number 3 which the last entry in a dynamic range into the new workbook:

```
     A          B        C
 1  18/08/2017  11  Medium risk
 2  18/08/2017  11  Medium risk
 3  19/08/2017  12  High risk
 4  18/08/2017  11  Medium risk
```

I hope to have been more clear with my question and I hope it may help. Many thanks for your help.

Comment: What have you tried already? Please provide a working sample of your code

Comment: This should help- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13510932/vba-excel-update-cell-in-another-workbook-without-opening-the-workbook

Comment: You just can not paste into a workbook without opening it. That's not possible.

Comment: I mean opening and closing it automatically

Comment: @peh He can however open it in another instance of Excel.

Comment: @LS_ᴅᴇᴠ sure there are many possibilities without *displaying* the file but none without opening it.

Comment: I am interested not in displaying the  workbook sheet target only. As has been said in the lines before for sure it needs to be opened. Sorry about the confusion. Many  Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Open Excel file for reading with VBA without display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/579797/open-excel-file-for-reading-with-vba-without-display). First answer shows how to open a file without displaying it. For *how to copy a range* and *[how to find the last used row](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11169920/3219613)* there are also many examples here on Stack Overflow. Put together some code and if you got stuck come here back again with your code and your questions.

Comment: Thank you very much